# Can I combine the monk's Martial Arts feature with the Hunter ranger's Horde Breaker feature?

Tags: dnd-5e, class-feature, monk, ranger, action-economy

Can I use the monk's Martial Arts feature on the second attack granted by the Hunter ranger's Horde Breaker feature (i.e., hit the first target with a weapon, use Martial Arts to make an unarmed strike, then use Horde Breaker to jump to the second target and repeat)?

I know I can't use Horde Breaker multiple times. My question is: Does Horde Breaker give me another full attack round, thus allowing me to use Martial Arts again in that attack's bonus round?

Answer (score 12):

### Attack Sources

**Horde Breaker** reads (emphasis added)...

> *Once on each of your turns* when you make a weapon attack, you can make another attack with the same weapon against a different creature that is within 5 feet of the original target and within range of your weapon.

...so it can only be used once after taking some other attack. There's no "repeat" and it's not separate from the initial attack in any way. It works much like the **Extra Attack** ability, just with special conditions. No matter what triggers it, it is *once on each of your turns* and only grants one attack.

Also note there's no such thing as a "full attack round" nor does an attack have a "bonus round". There are actions and bonus actions. Try not to think of "bonus action" as "an action that's a bonus", try to think of it like "bonus action" is a single word, like it's a separate thing in and of itself.

**Martial Arts** grants an additional attack as a bonus action.

> When you use the Attack action with an unarmed strike or a monk weapon on your turn, you can make one unarmed strike as a bonus action.

**Flurry of Blows** grants two additional attacks as a bonus action for the cost of 1 ki.

> Immediately after you take the Attack action on your turn, you can spend 1 ki point to make two unarmed strikes as a bonus action.

Monks get **Extra Attack** at L5:

> Beginning at 5th level, you can attack twice. instead of once, whenever you take the Attack action on your turn

### Attack Combinations

The character could make your normal attack (two via **Extra Attack** at L5) and one attack via **Horde Breaker** (assuming a valid target) as an *action*. It could then add one unarmed attack via **Martial Arts** (or two with Ki points via **Flurry of Blows**) as a *bonus action*.

**Maximum possible attacks, assuming all conditions and resources are available is five.** *Nothing* multiplies or triggers more than once. *Nothing* chains together more than described above.

### SCAG Weapon Cantrips

**Horde Breaker** does not specify that it is triggered by the *Attack action*,  just by a *weapon attack*. A character with access to some of the SCAG weapon cantrips could trigger it off that because they involve a weapon attack. The **Horde Breaker** attack wouldn't benefit from the cantrip's magic, but any *weapon attack* is enough to trigger it, and those cantrips include one.

### Movement (or "Who Gets Hit")

As far as attacks go, assuming you meet the requirements to make the attacks, you're allowed to freely [move between attacks](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/56056/can-monk-move-between-his-extra-and-bonus-attacks). 5E puts no restrictions on that.

Comment: Horde Breaker only works on your turn. "Once on each of your turns ..." You can't use it with ready actions. You could use it with the attack from haste, though.

Comment: @Nick Good catch on an old answer. I've removed the Haste section entirely. I don't agree with your assertion that Horde Breaker can be used with Haste. Haste is quite clear about being only one attack.

Comment: Ah true, so even if it would trigger, haste prevents you making more than 1 attack.

Answer (score 0):

No,

Martial Arts is a bonus action that can only be taken once per combat round (unless something specifically states otherwise.). Horde breaker allows an extra attack, as part of the same action as the first attack.